# How to show fixed div in middle of screen when screen show bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, absolute

I design a page with many small image and i like when small images clicked then open a fixed div and show my large image, it's work perfect for image that in up of page but when scroll drop down to bottom of page it's now work well, what is truble, you can see it in this page: http://www.3dcreate.ir/New3DCreate/Pages/Gallery/3DGallery/3dg_Chosen.php

HTML CODE:

```
<!-- This is Div of Large Image and Background Shade -->
<div class="BackgroudShade"></div>
<div class="DivOfImage"><img class="LargeImage"/></div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.DivOfImage {
    border: 8px solid #FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

JQuery CODE:

```
function LoadShowDiv () {
    $('.BackgroudShade').slideDown(800);   // shade of background will be visible
    $(".DivOfImage").show();               // Div of Large Image will be visible          
// When Image loaded successful then set width,height and top,left of Large Image Div 
// but i want set top,left when screen is scroll down to bottom of page
// then show Div at middle of screen in every time
    $('.LargeImage').load(function() {     
       $('.DivOfImage').width($('.LargeImage').width());
       $('.DivOfImage').height($('.LargeImage').height());
       var LeftPostion = (WidthOfScreen - $('.LargeImage').width()) / 2;
       var TopPostion = (HeightOfScreen - $('.LargeImage').height()) / 2;
       $(".DivOfImage").offset({ top: TopPostion, left: LeftPostion});
       $('.LargeImage').show(1000);
    })
}

$('#SmallImage').click(function(){
    $('.LargeImage').attr('src','LargeImage.jpg');
    LoadShowDiv();
})
```

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel and not use one of these handy lightboxes out there?

Comment: please see it in this page: http://www.3dcreate.ir/New3DCreate/Pages/Gallery/3DGallery/3dg_Chosen.php

Comment: Isn't css `position: fixed;` where you are looking for? this way the image always stays at the given offset(center), even when you scroll down or up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure, but why dont you try:

```
$(".DivOfImage").css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': TopPostion + 'px', 'left': LeftPostion + 'px'});
```

instead of

```
$(".DivOfImage").offset({ top: TopPostion, left: LeftPostion});
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, i was remove css code and set css of DIV in jquery, and it was work truly, Thanks